# C#: AWSClientFactory,.cs not found when trying to insert image into amazon s3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I am trying to insert an image into the Amazon s3 bucket. But I am getting the following error.

**AWSClientFactory.cs is not found.**

I am using Amazon SDK version 2.3.55.2

Here is my Cs code.

```
public string InsertFileToBucket(string fileName, Stream FileStream)
        {

            using (s3 = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey,RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();

                request.BucketName = _s3ImageBucketName;
                request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
                request.Key = fileName;
                request.InputStream = FileStream;
                PutObjectResponse response = s3.PutObject(request);

            }
            return fileName;
        }
```

[image]

In this code, I am converting the image to stream and passing it to this class. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are you getting this error are runtime or compile time?

Comment: I'd say compile time as `using (s3` will not compile

Comment: i m getting it on runtime

Comment: Can you check the exception details with it's message? And also see if there is any InnerException and share the message of that too here?

Comment: I have added a screenshot for your reference